# Using Left Join instead of Union

Tags: sql-server

Currently I am using `UNION` statement to retrieve data from two tables. Can I use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `UNION`?

```
SELECT count(*), emp
FROM
(
    SELECT *,  name + '|' + age as emp  
    FROM Employee As E With(NoLock)
    WHERE name = 'X'
    And age In (1, 2)
    AND active = 'Y'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT H.*, H.name + '|' + H.age AS emp  
    FROM Employee_History As H With(NoLock)
    Inner Join Employee As E With(NoLock) On E.id = H.id
    WHERE H.name = 'X'
    And H.age In (1, 2)
    And E.active != 'Y'
    AND H.salary in 
    (
        SELECT MAX(H2.salary) 
        From Employee_History As H2 With(NoLock)
        group by H2.id 
    )    
) AS A 
GROUP BY A.emp
ORDER BY A.emp
```

Comment: Does this query actually run? I would expect that "! =" would generate an error of some kind.

Comment: @Isaac <> is equal to != in MS SQL Server (Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-exclamation?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @user2410266 I think, you can do it using 'FULL OUTER JOIN' and 'Case'. But most simple method still is 'UNION ALL'.

Comment: Thanks,Yes this query works.The reason I want to use join for better performance

Comment: @Gurcan I knew that <> is equivalent to !=. I thought that ! = (note the space between ! and =) would not work. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Using UNION ALL will result in more rows and thus a greater count. A JOIN will result in less rows (but more columns) and a lesser count. What is right depends on your objective. Can you provide sample data and expected output?